# How to read image file name and extension using camera plugin in ionic2

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

Everyone

i want to get image name with image extension using camera plugin. how we can achieve that in ionic2. Thanks

**Here is my code:**

// image picker function

```
ImagePick() {

    let options = {
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        quality: 100,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        correctOrientation: true
    };
    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

// If it's base64:
        this.base64Image = imageData;

    }, (err) => {

    });
  }
```

Comment: you got your answer or not ? plz update ... i m having same problem

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `console.log()` or `debugger;` it can be used to log out things or inspect properties. You will want to have a look in `imageData` which is returned from the promise and would guess it will at least contain the file path. There is lots of info online about how to get a filename from a file path.

Comment: basically i want to get base64 string as well as filename.
base64 string is default in that we can't not get filename.
for getting filename we need to change option to FILE_URI from which we can get filename but not base64 string. how to get both at the same time with same option ?

Comment: I was in the same situation but I found a "fix". We don't need the file extension!! Even if the file is a png, we can do "data:image/jpeg;base64," + DATA_URL instead of "data:image/png;base64," + DATA_URL and the image will be valid!!